# Alter table structure without violating primary key and unique constraints

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints, primary-key

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4kk0.png) is a logical model that I have.

Below are table structures and their constraints

Doctor

```
CREATE TABLE doctor (
    doctor_id      NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    doctor_title   VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
    doctor_fname   VARCHAR2(50),
    doctor_lname   VARCHAR2(50),
    doctor_phone   CHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE doctor ADD CONSTRAINT doctor_pk PRIMARY KEY ( doctor_id );
```

Procedure

```
CREATE TABLE procedure (
    proc_code          NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    proc_name          VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    proc_description   VARCHAR2(300) NOT NULL,
    proc_time          NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    proc_std_cost      NUMBER(7, 2) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE procedure ADD CONSTRAINT procedure_pk PRIMARY KEY ( proc_code );

ALTER TABLE procedure ADD CONSTRAINT proc_name_unq UNIQUE ( proc_name );
```

Admission

```
CREATE TABLE admission (
    adm_no          NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    adm_date_time   DATE NOT NULL,
    adm_discharge   DATE,
    patient_id      NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    doctor_id       NUMBER(4) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE admission ADD CONSTRAINT admission_pk PRIMARY KEY ( adm_no );    --surrogate key

ALTER TABLE admission ADD CONSTRAINT admission_nk UNIQUE ( patient_id,
                                                           adm_date_time );
```

Admission Procedure

```
CREATE TABLE adm_prc (
    adprc_no           NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
    adprc_date_time    DATE NOT NULL,
    adprc_pat_cost     NUMBER(7, 2) NOT NULL,
    adprc_items_cost   NUMBER(6, 2) NOT NULL,
    adm_no             NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    proc_code          NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    request_dr_id      NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    perform_dr_id      NUMBER(4)
);
ALTER TABLE adm_prc ADD CONSTRAINT adm_prc_pk PRIMARY KEY ( adprc_no );    --surrogate key
ALTER TABLE adm_prc ADD CONSTRAINT adm_prc_nk UNIQUE ( adprc_date_time,
                                                       adm_no );
ALTER TABLE adm_prc
    ADD CONSTRAINT admission_admprc FOREIGN KEY ( adm_no )
        REFERENCES admission ( adm_no );
ALTER TABLE adm_prc
    ADD CONSTRAINT doctor_performadmprc FOREIGN KEY ( perform_dr_id )
        REFERENCES doctor ( doctor_id );
ALTER TABLE adm_prc
    ADD CONSTRAINT doctor_requestadmprc FOREIGN KEY ( request_dr_id )
        REFERENCES doctor ( doctor_id );
```

Item Treatment

```
CREATE TABLE item_treatment (
    adprc_no             NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
    item_code            CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    it_qty_used          NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    it_item_total_cost   NUMBER(8, 2) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE item_treatment
    ADD CONSTRAINT item_treatment_pk PRIMARY KEY ( adprc_no,item_code);
ALTER TABLE item_treatment
    ADD CONSTRAINT admprc_itemtreatment FOREIGN KEY ( adprc_no )
        REFERENCES adm_prc ( adprc_no );
ALTER TABLE item_treatment
    ADD CONSTRAINT admprc_itemtreatment FOREIGN KEY ( adprc_no )
        REFERENCES adm_prc ( adprc_no );
ALTER TABLE item_treatment
    ADD CONSTRAINT item_itemtreatment FOREIGN KEY ( item_code )
        REFERENCES item ( item_code );
```

In a fictitious hospital, every time an admission procedure is completed for a patient admission, the lead doctor who performed the procedure is recorded under the `perform_dr_id` in `adm_prc` table. Even if a team of doctors perform the procedure, only the lead doctor is recorded.

The hospital now wishes to record all the doctors who performed in the admission procedure including an Ancillary doctor (assisting doctor).

I have altered the `adm_prc` table to include ancillary doctors

```
ALTER TABLE ADM_PRC ADD ANCILLARY_DR_ID NUMBER(4);
ALTER TABLE ADM_PRC
    ADD CONSTRAINT DOCTOR_PERFORM_ANCILLARY FOREIGN KEY ( ANCILLARY_DR_ID )
        REFERENCES DOCTOR ( DOCTOR_ID );
```

I need to change the structure of the database is such a way that, there should be multiple records for the same admission procedure as there can be many doctors assisting in a single admission procedure. For example, I should be able to insert the following records in `adm_prc` table

```
adprc_no  adprc_date_time  adprc_pat_cost  adprc_items_cost  adm_no  proc_code 
 request_dr_id  perform_dr_id  ancillary_dr_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         14/03/2019       100             100               1234    1234         
 10             10             12
1         14/03/2019       100             100               1234    1234         
 10             10             13
```

However, this violates primary key constraint `adm_prc_pk`

I'm stuck at this point and unable to proceed further. Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: As there is no n:1 correspondence between the admission and the assisting doctors you should not add a column to the admissions but create a new detail table (means fk to the admissions) where you can save multiple records per admission (one for every assistant doctor).

Comment: Thank you Radagast81 for the suggestion. I had to create a new table after all. Somehow I wasn't seeing it. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new satellite table (say ADM_PRC_DR_DTLS) to hold adprc_no and corresponding dr_id details.
adprc_no of ADM_PRC_DR_DTLS would refer to the ADM_PRC's adprc_no as a Foreign Key.

Comment: Yes, this worked. By creating a new table ADM_PRC_DR_DTLS with ADM_PRC's adprc_no as a Foreign Key and doctor_id from doctor as foreign key. I made both columns as primary key and now for the same adprc_no I can have many ancillary doctors. Thank you!